# Rails, checking roles with Role Model gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-roles

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4. I use bootstrap, devise simple form and role_model gems.

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RoleModel

  #reminder for roles (RoleModel): always add new roles to the end of this line - don't change the order
  roles :admin, :manager, 
        :student, :educator, :researcher, :ktp, :faculty_manager, :ip_asset_manager,  
        :sponsor, 
        :project_manager, :representative, # for both uni and industry
        :grantor, :investor, :adviser, :innovation_consultant, :panel_member,
        :participant, :guest, :pending

  # Other stuff goes here

end
```

Then in my profile view, I have a form where I ask users where they are from. I want to phrase the question differently depending on the user's role and I want to use a different array of options depending on that role. Eg, if the current user is a student, then the array should be populated with a list of universities.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
  <% if current_user.profile.has_any_role?(:student, :educator, :researcher, :ktp, :faculty_manager, :ip_asset_manager) %>
    <%= f.label  'Select your university',   :class => 'question-project' %>
  <% elsif current_user.profile.has_role?(:sponsor) %>                  
    <%= f.label  'Select your organisation',   :class => 'question-project' %>    
  <% elsif current_user.profile.has_any_role?(:grantor, :investor, :adviser, :innovation_consultant, :panel_member) %>  
  <% end %>                
</div>

<div class="col-md-7">
  <div class="response-project">
    <% if current_user.profile.has_any_role?(:student, :educator, :researcher, :ktp, :faculty_manager, :ip_asset_manager) %>                
      <%= f.collection_select :university_id, University.all, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select your university' %>
    <% elsif current_user.profile.has_role?(:sponsor) %>
      <%= f.collection_select :organisation_id, Organisation.all, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select your organisation' %>
    <% elsif current_user.profile.has_any_role?(:grantor, :investor, :adviser, :innovation_consultant, :panel_member) %>  
      <%= f.collection_select :firm_id, Firm.all, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select your organisation' %>
    <% else %>
      <%=  current_user.profile.id %>
    <% end %>
```

I have the final else statement to prove that all of the above isn't working. When I try this, using the user with the role :student, should send me down the first route. It doesn't work. I get the user.profile.id instead.

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

Comment: `<%= puts current_user.profile.has_any_role?(:student, :educator, :researcher, :ktp, :faculty_manager, :ip_asset_manager) %>` what is the boolean value, please paste the result here.

Comment: `<%= puts current_user.profile.has_role? :student %>`, for this what is the o/p?

Comment: <%= puts current_user.profile.has_role? :student %> gives nothing. If i try without the 'puts' I get false. If I try using the profile id in the console, I get role = student

Answer (score 2):

You forgotten to add the `require 'role_model'` on top of model class

**UPDATE**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'role_model'

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :roles_mask
  include RoleModel

  #reminder for roles (RoleModel): always add new roles to the end of this line - don't change the order
  roles_attribute :roles_mask

  roles :admin, :manager, 
    :student, :educator, :researcher, :ktp, :faculty_manager, :ip_asset_manager,  
    :sponsor, 
    :project_manager, :representative, # for both uni and industry
    :grantor, :investor, :adviser, :innovation_consultant, :panel_member,
    :participant, :guest, :pending

  # Other stuff goes here

end
```

In your case `u.roles` is empty:

```
> u.roles
=> #<RoleModel::Roles: {}>
```

From console you need to assign the roles:

```
u = User.first
> u.roles
=> #<RoleModel::Roles: {}> 
> u.roles= [:admin]
=> [:admin] 
> u.roles
=> #<RoleModel::Roles: {:admin}> 
> u.roles << :manager
=> #<RoleModel::Roles: {:admin, :manager}> 
> u.roles
=> #<RoleModel::Roles: {:admin, :manager}> 
> u.has_any_role? :author, :manager
=> true
```

For further [Reference](https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model)

Comment: Hi, i didn't realise you have to require it as well as include it. I tried this suggestion, but it didn't work. I still get the same output as my original question